# How do you link to a specific tab in a tabGroup with a button in a different tab's window?

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium

I have a tab group with 5 tabs, one of these tabs is the "Home" screen. I would like the user to be able to click a button in a window of any of the tabs to get back to the home screen.

Currently the closest method I have found creates a new window, which breaks the navigation.

```
var win_home = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
url:'home.js'
});

btn_home.addEventListener("click", function() {
 Ti.UI.currentTab.open(win_home,{animated:true});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code under your button event listener.

```
// get the tab group object in the file
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.currentTabGroup; 

btn_home.addEventListener("click", function() {

   // pass the id of your home tab, i used 1 here
   tabGroup.tabs[1].active = true;
});
```

Comment: why not just use the built in method `tabGroup.setActiveTab(INDEX)`?

Comment: Also your home tab index is most likely 0 not 1 as JS arrays start at 0

Comment: The index of tab  is mentioned in comments.

Comment: tabGroup.setActiveTab(INDEX) is mostly used in app.js

Comment: Muhammad, your solution worked perfectly, thank you. I did change the index to 0 as Brian mentioned. I am curious where you discover these things as there seems to be some basic info that I am unable to locate.

Comment: A lot of the documentation isn't in the API but you can search the KS repo for what Kevin did to get it to work. https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/

Comment: What I do: play around in the KS app until I find a screen that does what I want. Then I go look at its source code.

Comment: @Dogweather so true :-) they need to work on their documentation heavily still